# How do you convert rows to columns in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot

I have a table with the following columns: `user_id`, `grade`.

```
user_id | grade
1         k
1         3
2         4
2         5
3         2
```

I would like to be able to make a table that looks like `user_id`, `grade_k`, `grade_1`, etc, with a true or false for each grade if the user teaches that grade.

It seems like you could use `crosstab` to do this,  but could someone show me an example?

Desired output:

```
user_id | grade_k | grade_1 | grade_2 | grade_3 | grade_4 | grade_5
1         1         0         0         1         0         0
2         0         0         0         0         1         1
3         0         0         1         0         0         0
```

The reason I want to do this is that this format will make it easier to do filtering in a data visualization tool.

Comment: Put the desired results for the given example data please. I'm also curious can a user that teaches grade X also teach grades lower than X, which the desired result will help answer

Comment: can you add the required output ?

Answer (score 3):

Using filtered aggregation is typically much easier than using the `crosstab()` function:

```
select user_id, 
       max(grade) filter(where grade = 'k') is not null as teaches_grade_k,
       max(grade) filter(where grade = '1') is not null as teaches_grade_1,
       max(grade) filter(where grade = '2') is not null as teaches_grade_2,
       max(grade) filter(where grade = '3') is not null as teaches_grade_3,
       max(grade) filter(where grade = '4') is not null as teaches_grade_5
       max(grade) filter(where grade = '5') is not null as teaches_grade_5
from users
group by user_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option, similar to a filtered aggregation, would be to use a regular array aggregation and check for existence, like

```
WITH users (user_id, grade) AS (
    VALUES
        (1, 'k'),
        (1, '1'),
        (2, '4'),
        (2, '5'),
        (3, '2')
),
user_grades AS (
    SELECT user_id, array_agg(grade) AS grades
    FROM users
    GROUP BY user_id
)
SELECT
    user_id,
    'k' = ANY(grades) AS teaches_k,
    '1' = ANY(grades) AS teaches_1,
    '2' = ANY(grades) AS teaches_2,
    '3' = ANY(grades) AS teaches_3,
    '4' = ANY(grades) AS teaches_4,
    '5' = ANY(grades) AS teaches_5
FROM
    user_grades
```