# CrossTab function posgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, crosstab, postgres-crosstab

I am new to postgresql and even newer to crosstab but from what I have read, the below query should work:

```
select * from crosstab(
$$select distinct "AccountNumber" , "ProductCategory", sum("ProductQuantity") sm
from "MsfDataRecords" mdr
group by "ProductCategory", "AccountNumber", "ProductQuantity"$$
)as ct("AccountNumber" text , "ProductCategory" text , sm numeric)
```

But this errors with `SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: return and sql tuple descriptions are incompatible`

I have checked all the data types and they are correct. I'm not sure if it is to do with the sum function though.

Any help appreciated

Comment: Using conditional aggregation is almost always easier than using `crosstab()`

Comment: Thanks. Could you give an example or point me to any tutorials please?

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58062225/how-to-create-a-postgresql-pivot-table-that-pivots-multiple-columns) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56568101/using-postgres-tablefunc-crosstab-to-count-incorrect-answers) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67174469/how-do-you-convert-rows-to-columns-in-postgres/67175030#67175030) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66743282/dynamic-transpose-for-unknown-row-value-into-column-name-on-postgres/66744030#66744030)

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Comment: Thanks for your help. Very much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in the last line. The columns represented in the ct are selected in this line. Instead of

```
)as ct("AccountNumber" text , "ProductCategory" text , sm numeric)
```

it should be

```
as ct(
    AccountNumber text, 
    ProductCategory1 numeric, 
    ProductCategory2 numeric, 
    ProductCategory3 numeric, 
    ..., 
    ProductCategoryN numeric)
```

Your `GROUP BY` clause also should only include the first and second column which are later on sorted.

Here's a [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=87df125a0525f4a4f8210b9c499460ba) example for illustration. Or if you prefer code here's an example code.

```
CREATE TABLE MsfDataRecords(
    AccountNumber text,
    ProductCategory text,
    ProductQuantity numeric
)
;

INSERT INTO MsfDataRecords(AccountNumber, ProductCategory, ProductQuantity) VALUES
    ('A1', 'Food', 3),
    ('A1', 'Food', 1),
    ('A2', 'Food', 3),
    ('A2', 'Electronics', 2),
    ('A2', 'Fashion', 10)
;

SELECT * FROM CROSSTAB(
    $$
    SELECT AccountNumber , ProductCategory, SUM(ProductQuantity) AS sm
    FROM MsfDataRecords AS mdr
    GROUP BY 1,2
    ORDER BY 1,2
    $$
)AS ct(
    AccountNumber text,
    Food numeric,
    Electronics numeric,
    Fashion numeric
)
;
```

Note that pivoting like this only works in **PostgreSQL**.